# Property binding in Web API complex model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I am trying to get Web API binding a special property on my model using two different query-string values or request body. Take this model:

```
public class CustomEvent {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeInterval DateRange { get; set; }

}

public class TimeInterval {

    public DateTime StartDateUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateUtc { get; set; }

}
```

And this quick controller action:

```
[HttpPost, Route("events/add")]
public void AddEvent(CustomEvent event)
{
    // Get events
}
```

The url is hit with `/events/add` with the following JSON body:

```
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "This is the event name",
    "Start": "dd-mm-yyyy",
    "End": "dd-mm-yyyy"
}
```

The names of these JSON properties `Start` and `End` can not be changed, but I wish to bind these to my `TimeInterval` property on my model.

Is it possible to create property binding in WebAPI?

Ideally I am going to create a attribute on my `DateRange` property like `[TimeIntervalBind(StarDatetUtc = "Start", EndDateUtc = "End")]` to catch the fields name, but currently stuck whether I should use `IModelBinder` or one of the other alternatives in WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1: Create an intermediary model with properties named after your posted data, say:

```
public class myTemporaryEventModel(){
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

2: In your POST method, put `myTemporaryEventModel` as a parameter and then transform it into your CustomEvent class:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("events/add")]
public void AddEvent(myTemporaryEventModel postedData)
{
    TimeInteval interval = new TimeInterval(){
        StartDateUtc = postedData.Start,
        EndDateUtc = postedData.End
    }

    CustomEvent event = new CustomEvent(){
        Id = postedData.Id,
        Name = postedData.Name,
        DateRange = interval
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be best to create a ViewModel (CustomEventVM) which you would use in your request and in the action method which receives it you would simply create your models and work with them from the data that you receive in the ViewModel.